# How do I read an excel file in c# skipping the column headers?

Tags: c#, console-application

I am using SmartXLSX to read excel files successfully, but I'm facing a problem. My program is reading the column header's as a new row along with all the other rows from the spreadsheet. How should I update my program to skip the column header's and read the other rows.

```
 private void GetCompanies()
        {
            int count = 0;

            Companies = new List<Company>();

            string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            string path = Path.Combine(directory, "Toll-Companies.xlsx");


            SmartXLS.WorkBook WB = new WorkBook();
            WB.readXLSX(path);

            DataTable dt = WB.ExportDataTable();



                string CurrentType = string.Empty;
                string CurrentCategory = string.Empty;
                string Removerow = string.Empty;

                string b,c;
                //DataRow rowe = dt.Rows[0];
                //dt.Rows.Remove(rowe);
                //loop through each row

                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                   {


                    //Get company name in column c from Excel
                    c = dr[2].ToString();

                    //Get value in column B from Excel
                    b = dr[0].ToString();


                    if (b.StartsWith("Type:"))
                    {
                        CurrentType = b.Substring(6).Trim();
                    }

                    if (b.StartsWith("Primary Specialty"))
                    {
                        CurrentCategory = b.Substring(20).Trim();
                    }

                    //if company name is empy then skip row
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(c)) continue;

                    //string Type = dr[7].ToString();
                    //dt.Columns.Add(Type)

                    //string cmp_type = dr[0].ToString();
                    //if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmp_type) || cmp_type == "Type") continue;


                    var cmp = new Company();


                    cmp.company_type = CurrentType;
                    cmp.company_category = CurrentCategory;
                    cmp.name = dr[2].ToString();
                    Companies.Add(cmp);
                    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get the result you are seeking. I am unsure if you were looking for a method in the SmartXLSX library.

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    if(count==0) continue;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for and skip first row...